# Unable to execute testng in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testng

I'm usually able to run my test with testng just fine. Now when I click "run as testng", all it does is as shown in the image below. There's no output or error message in the console.

[Eclipse TestNg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGwjn.jpg)

The image is showing 2 tasks; happens that I clicked twice when I captured the image.

To drill down the problem, I'm just running a very simple test:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
```

I tried to restart PC, restart Eclipse, install fresh copy of Eclipse/testng and JDK but no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: There is a test result listening job running in the image. Also please do share some sample test that you tried executing. The quality of the question needs to be improved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is related to the change i made to the host file. got it working again by removing all the losthost entries in the host file